# Delete all Enterprise Keywords in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, enterprise-keywords

How can I delete all Enterprise Keywords in our **Sharepoint Online**. It seems that the Term Store is already populated with many, many entries.

Is there a way to "reset" or delete all Enterprise keywords?

In GUI, I can't find a "Delete ALL"-Button. How about powershell? Does some have a script?

Answer (score 0):

### How to delete Enterprise Keywords using SharePoint CSOM in PowerShell

`Clear-Keywords.ps1` PS script:

```
param (
     [string]$UserName,
     [string]$Password,
     [string]$Url
 )

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy")



Function Get-SPOCredentials([string]$UserName,[string]$Password)
{
    $SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    return New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword)
}


Function Clear-Keywords([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$Context)
{
    $taxSession = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession]::GetTaxonomySession($Context)
    $termStore = $taxSession.GetDefaultKeywordsTermStore()
    $keywords = $termStore.KeywordsTermSet.Terms
    $Context.Load($keywords)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()

    $keywords | % { $_.DeleteObject() }
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()
}


$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
$context.Credentials = Get-SPOCredentials -UserName $UserName -Password $Password
Clear-Keywords -Context $context
$context.Dispose()
```

Usage

```
.\Clear-Keywords.ps1 -Url "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/" -UserName "username@contoso.onmicrosoft.com" -Password "password"
```